# how to bring live magento site to localhost without effecting live site

Tags: magento

i want a live site to be on local host and without effecting any functionality of live magento site. i have tried many way of doing that but have not get any result from it.

steps i tried are :
1. taken database from magento live site by entering into cpanel(by ftp access) > phpmyadmin > exported all the files to my local machine and i imported all the data to my local phpmyadmin.

2.taken all neccessary files from cpanel > file manager > all files (for example p_html, .htpassword, .trash, access log, etc file and many more) and put it on my local machine and then  i put the file in folder and kept it into C:\xampp\htdocs\ all file ( in folder ).

3 Replaced the path of live site with localhost:1234 in the all sql files where applicable taken in step one.

but still not working .
Any help will be appreciated....

Comment: have you clear your cache after installing on local server? and what not working in your case?

Comment: What happens when you try to navigate to it? Does it give you an error, redirect or something else?

Comment: i actually deleted the cache folder which was in var folder, and i used this(localhost:1234/magentowork/public_html) path on browser to see whether its working or not and its was not working .....                 and my directory stucture where i kept the magento file downloaded in step 2 of my question is C:\xampp\htdocs\magentowork\

Comment: Once again, what happens when you try to navigate to it? Does it give you an error, does it redirect you to another URL or something else?

Comment: when i use this url http://localhost:1234/magentowork/public_html it give this error:                                                 Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

Comment: Please check my updated answer and read the instructions provided by the url.

Answer (score 19):

**Copy your LIVE Magento store to your Local computer:**

1. Download the magento files using any ftp client.
2. Export the database from live server.
3. Put the downloaded Magento files in your localhost root folder.
4. Create a blank database(lets say it 'local-database') in your local computer and import the database backup that you exported from the live one.
5. Delete/Rename the file app/etc/local.xml
6. Re-install the Magento using the local-database.
7. After installation, go to Admin section and then

> (i)Flush all cache. (ii)Re-Index all data. (iii)Flush all cache.

That's it. You are done.

***N.B.*** If you have domain specific Modules installed, those modules will not work here.

Seems very simple right. ***Believe me, it is that simple.***

If you face any problem in installing your Magento in localcomputer, here is a post that may come in handy: http://www.insync.co.in/how-to-install-magento-on-wamp-server-localhost-localcomputer/

Comment: +1. Sir. You saved my life. Deleting the local.xml was the key.

Comment: when you say "go to admin section", my local magento install redirects me to the live version. What else would I need to delete?

Comment: did you reinstall? This is happening because the base URL is still of the live site

Comment: @Subrata, I'm new to Magento, so can you provide details on re-install part?

Comment: @cnu The answer given here is for Magento 1.x for latest Magento 2.x things works differently. What do you want to know exactly? Here by reinstall means, if you delete local.xml and open the site llink in browser, it will ask you to proceed with installation part, I was talking about that.

Answer (score 3):

**Steps:**

1. Download the files to the local project folder.
2. Create a new local DB and import the live database backup/dump.
3. Update app/etc/local.xml file with local DB parameters(Host name, DB
   name, DB username, DB password)
4. Magento have the project URL saved in 2 places(secure URL and
   unsecure URL) in the table `core_config_data`. We need to update
   that in imported local DB to the local URL(9th and 10th record in
   the table).
5. Delete the cache: Delete the contents in `var` folder(That folder
   contains reports and logs too. I assume that you won't need it as
   this is a separate installation)

**The local copy will most probably work by now but there are possibilities that it would not. Things to do in this case:**

1. If you are getting redirected to the live site, check the .htaccess
   file for redirects(For various reasons there may be a redirect
   defined in the file)
2. If you are getting forbidden error, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40925879/1788684) will come in handy(Usually occurs in linux systems)

**There may still be some problems probably theme or module specific. In this case you will need to debug the project and find out what the problem is. Xdebug will come in handy in this situation for boosting the debug process :)**

Subrata's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19633132/1788684) will conflict with some of the Magento Modules installed and will not allow you to re-install Magento in local. I follow these steps and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just give a permission (0777) after take a backup to that folder in your local PC

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have to change the secure and unsecure base_url in your database.
These can be found in the 'core_config_data' table.
Paths:
`web/unsecure/base_url` 
`web/secure/base_url`

If you want to access your local version of Magento via localhost, you'll have to set localhost as your base_url.

After that you need to clear your cache folder.

EDIT:
To install and run Magento on your local PC using XAMPP, please follow these steps:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_on_windows_with_xampp_and_wamp

Comment: i have change my path by going on phpmyadmin and then on web/unsecure/base_url and changed its value to my path which is localhost:1234/magentowork/public_html. and same with web/secure/base_url too. and clear the cache from public_html/var folder...   but it is still not working. please give some brief reply ... thank for the earlier help ...

Comment: i actually deleted the cache folder which was in var folder, and i used this(localhost:1234/magentowork/public_html) path on browser to see whether its working or not and its was not working .....                 and my directory stucture where i kept the magento file downloaded in step 2 of my question is C:\xampp\htdocs\magentowork\ ........         its a request if u give some precious time of urs and give step in detail from beginning to end so that i figure it out where i have made a mistake and my localhost will get working