# Link is redirecting remote host instead of local host

Tags: php, magento, url, redirect, magento2

I have downloaded my magento based website from remote host. After making configuration according to localhost and importing database when I hit the 
url of site on localhost **localhost/queens** instead of open website from local host url is redirected to remote host. and open from there.

My Question is 
Why it is doing that?
What can i do to open my website on localhost.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42718836/4248328  or  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOIzGpXCuT4

Comment: Or https://www.elementarydigital.co.uk/how-to-migrate-your-magento-store-from-one-host-to-another/

Comment: Thankyou for the help.